# No Automatic Cast from `int` to `float` with Template Function

Tags: c++, c++11, template-function

After years of coding in c++, today I was asked a simple question, but indeed I couldn't find its answer and so here I am guys.

Besides wondering **why** this error is happening, I want to know **how** I can solve below error by modifying just the **template function** (without changing the `main()` function)

```
template <class T>
T Add(T first, T second)
{
    return first + second;
}

int main()
{
    auto sample_1 = Add(1, 2); // Works
    auto sample_2 = Add(1.f, 2.f); // Works
    auto sample_3 = Add(1.f, 2); // Error: no instance matches the argument types: (double, int)
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: introduce `class T2` or make `second` non-deducible with `decltype(first) second` ?

Comment: Interesting scenario though. I think a default compiler switch should have been implemented to handle such cases...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Besides wondering why this error is happening,

When you call `Add(1.f, 2)`, the first argument type is `float` and the second argument type is `int`.

The compiler has to convert either the first argument to an `int` or the second argument to a `float`. Since both of them will require a conversion, they are equally good candidates. One cannot be preferred over the other.

> I want to know how I can solve below error by modifying just the template function

You can change the function template to:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
auto Add(T1 first, T2 second)
{
    return first + second;
}
```

or to (thanks @PiotrSkotnicki):

```
template <class T>
T Add(T first, decltype(first) second)
{
    return first + second;
}
```

In this case, the type of `second` is not deduced from the argument being passed to the function. Type of `first` is deduced from the first argument and the type of `second` is forced to be the same as the type of `first`.

```
Add(1.2f, 2);  // The first argument is deduced to be float
               // The second argument is forced to be float.

Add(2, 1.2f);  // The first argument is deduced to be int
               // The second argument is forced to be int.
```

Comment: You should explain how that magical second example works, for when Piotr's comment is inevitably nuked.

Answer (score 9):

Just do:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
auto Add(T1 first, T2 second)
{
    return first + second;
}
```

As with unique `T`, it is deduced once as `int`, once as `double`...

Answer (score 4):

When you have

```
template <class T>
T Add(T first, T second)
```

the type of `first` and `second` need to be the same.  If you want to take two different types then you can add a second template parameter

```
template <class T1, class T2>
auto Add(T1 first, T2 second)
```

or for C++11

```
template <class T1, class T2>
auto Add(T1 first, T2 second) -> decltype(first + second)
```

Comment: `T` is undeclared so cannot be used as the return type, and writing the return type correctly then `T1` and `T2` are different is possible, but complicated enough (unless using `auto` as in other answers) that it probably needs to be addressed for your answer to really be useful to the OP.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is trying to deduce the template type that it can use to create a function that matches the signature. Since the parameters are different types, it's unable to do so.

You could specify the type explicitly:

```
auto sample_3 = Add<float>(1.f, 2);
```

But you say you don't want to do that.

You can change the function to take *two* template types:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
T1 Add(T1 first, T2 second)
{
    T1 p;
    p = first + second;
    return p;
}
```

But now you'll have to make an assumption about which type to return.

I've never tried to use `auto` as the return type, but apparently it works: http://ideone.com/1qO95w

```
template <class T1, class T2>
auto Add(T1 first, T2 second)
{
    auto p = first + second;
    return p;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. note that `T` is undefined in your code.

Comment: @Emadpres thanks, that was a simple copy/paste error. I've also fleshed out the answer with `auto`.

Comment: It's new c++14 feature which I can't use it. thanks anyway and I give your effort +1 :]

Comment: Which type to return? decltype(first+second) obviously. or however the hell you explicitly write that.

Answer (score 2):

Why write your own function when the standard already provided them?

In c++11, you can use:

```
#include <functional>
int main()
{
    auto sample_1 = std::plus<float> () ( 1, 2 ); // Works
    auto sample_2 = std::plus<float> () ( 1.f, 2.f ); // Works
    auto sample_3 = std::plus<float> () ( 1.f, 2 ); // Works
    return 0;
}
```

In c++14:

```
#include <functional>
int main()
{
    auto sample_1 = std::plus<> () ( 1, 2 ); // Works
    auto sample_2 = std::plus<> () ( 1.f, 2.f ); // Works
    auto sample_3 = std::plus<> () ( 1.f, 2 ); // Works
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know how I can solve below error by modifying just the template function

Like that:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
T1 Add(T1 first, T2 second)
{
    T1 p;
    p = first + second;
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    auto sample_1 = Add(1, 2);
    auto sample_2 = Add(1.f, 2.f);
    auto sample_3 = Add(1.f, 2);
    return 0;
}
```